# Apply Mui style inside pure html file - How?

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I have a react component that I need to convert to html + css file and js file.
In the react component I use mui for style, can I use in html also in the mui classes?

For example:
I have an Autocomplete input

```js
<Autocomplete
  options={peoples}
  getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
  value={
    peoples.find(c => c.name === data.peopleId) || null
  }
  onChange={(_, newValue) => {
    onPeopleChange(newValue ? newValue.name : '')
  }}
  fullWidth
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="People"
      required
      error={showValidation && !data.peopleId}
    />
  )}
  popupIcon={<KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
```

It looks like:

[image: input]

[image]

Is there any way to get this input with the style in html file?

Comment: It's not React that brings styles to the element. There are styles in the code of the component or somewhere else (in the component library). You can find these styles using devtools or investigate the source code of the component.

Comment: Thanks for youe quick response. Since I use React I can Install mui and get all the elements by hand, is there any way/any docs how can I use mui elements style without insert all the style inside my code? maybe by apply classes or something, I need all the behavior like the input name go up the input while typing (attached a shot) etc.

Comment: But why do you want to do it in HTML? Does server-side rendering satisfy your use case?

Comment: I need to send only the data that inserted into the inputs to any api.

Comment: Do you think if I'll create react app and build it, I will get all the relevant pure html + js to run and will get the same result?

Comment: Yes. I'm wondering if you only need to get those files or do you want to maintain (manually edit) them.

Comment: What do you mean? I need in the end one html and one js for my project. So maybe the way to do that is build react app and than take the build result into my project?

Comment: The build result is not suitable for manual editing. If you want to maintain it, you'd better keep the React project and just use the build result in deployment. I'm just not sure if this is suitable for your use case.

Comment: I need that html + js files for using inside chrome extension